# Problema de SQL, quiero mostrar dos columnas y me da errores de compatibilidad

Tags: sql, tablas

la situacion es la siguiente. El ejercicio plantea varias tablas relacionadas a resultados de partidos de futbol, jugadores, clubes y sus nombres etc. Para este ejercicio, solamente utilizo dos tablas: una 'general' y la otra 'jugadores'[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Serian esas tablas con esos campos, y a mi me piden encontrar la menor diferencia (es decir, la mayor cantidad de goles en contra) en la categoria 84, y proyectar tanto esa menor diferencia como el nombre de los jugadores pertenecientes

Mi código hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
SELECT

    MIN(Diferencia) AS MenorDiferencia,
    j.nombre AS NombreJugador


FROM general g
INNER JOIN jugadores j ON g.Id_Club = j.Id_Club
WHERE j.Categoria = 84;
```

Comment: ¿Qué son "errores de compatibilidad"? Además, muestra la estructura de tus tablas _como texto, con formato_.

Comment: te faltó decir qué es lo que obtienes y qué es lo que necesitas obtener. No como descripción sino como ejemplo de la salida